# should I add "s" to other verbs in my sentence?

Tags: grammar

my sentences:

> 1.If anyone **visits** the website and **click/ clicks** on a link...

> 2.They reward anyone who **signs up** to the platform and **complete/ completes** some simple tasks

Should I add "s" to the second verbs "click" and "complete" too?

I'm confused because the subject is "anyone"!

Comment: Yes. 'Anyone' is any individual person, so it takes a singular verb.

Comment: 1. Both verbs of each sentence have the same subject, **anyone**, so they both need the same person marker. 2. **Anyone** is 3rd person singular, therefore you need **s** for each verb connected to **anyone** in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Subject-Verb Agreement

> Subjects and verbs must AGREE with one another in number (singular or plural).  Thus, if a subject is singular, its verb must also be singular; if a subject is plural, its verb must also be plural.

Ref [https://webapps.towson.edu](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sub-verb.htm)

A.

> 1.If anyone **visits** the website and **clicks** on a link...

If you **visit** the website and **click** on a link...

> 2.They reward anyone who **signs** up to the platform and **completes** some simple tasks

They reward you if you **sign** up to the platform and **complete** some simple tasks